# Error using VideoWriter

Tags: matlab, video

I am creating an `avi` file from a bunch of frames using `VideoWriter` in MATLAB. But I'm getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.writeVideo at 339
The 'cdata' field of FRAME must not be empty
```

Since I can create `jpg` files from the same script, I know an image pops up.

Here's my code:

```
%% Graph one site at a time
    writerObj = VideoWriter(['US_O3_MDA8_EUS_' num2str(years(y)) '_10-90.avi']);
    writerObj.FrameRate = 1;
    open(writerObj);

% Map of conterminous US
nFrames = length(date); % Number of frames.
for k = 1:nFrames % Number of days
    ax = figure(1);
    ax = usamap({'TX','ME'});
    latlim = getm(ax, 'MapLatLimit');
    lonlim = getm(ax, 'MapLonLimit');
    states = shaperead('usastatehi',...
        'UseGeoCoords', true, 'BoundingBox', [lonlim', latlim']);
    geoshow(ax, states, 'FaceColor', 'none')
    % framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off

    hold on

    % Plot data
    h = scatterm(ax,str2double(Lat_O3{k}), str2double(Lon_O3{k}), 40, str2double(data_O3{k})*1000, 'filled'); 

    % Set colorbar and title info

    % Capture the frame
    frame = getframe;
    writeVideo(writerObj,frame);

    clf
end
    % Save as AVI file 
    close(writerObj);
    close(gcf)
```

Comment: The error is happening because the colour data when you run `getframe` is actually non-existent.  Place a breakpoint right at `writeVideo(writerObj,frame);`.  Take a look at the `frame` data structure and see what the `cdata` field is.  Is it empty?

Comment: I think `getframe` doesn't work under `hold on`.

Comment: I should change that - I don't actually have `hold on` right before `getframe`. I have some other codes for the `colorbar` and `title` before `getframe`

Comment: @rayryeng When I put it right at `writeVideo(writerObj,frame);` I don't have a `cdata` variable in the workspace at all.

Comment: The most likely reason is because the frame isn't being displayed when you're doing `scatterm`.  This is probably because you are assigning the statement to a handle, which is `h`.  Typical behaviour when assigning a plot to a handle is that the figure **does not show itself**, and it would be up to you to show the figure on your own.  If you don't want this, remove the `h` assignment and try running your code again.  That is, replace `h = scatterm(...);` to `scatterm(...);`

Comment: Also, `getframe` takes a snapshot of the **current** frame in focus.  If there is no plot/frame window currently open, `getframe` will not return anything meaningful.  Therefore, if what I suggested doesn't work, try doing: `frame = getframe(h);` so that it takes a snapshot of the plot that is provided by the handle `h`.  In this case, it would be your `scatterm` plot.

Comment: I tried with `scatterm(...);` and I got this: `Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may be invalid.`

Comment: For clarification, when you say to do `frame=getframe(h);`, do you mean try it with `h = scatterm(...);`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Try that and let me know.

Comment: @rayreng That didn't work. I got the same `??? Error using ==> VideoWriter.VideoWriter>VideoWriter.writeVideo at 339
The 'cdata' field of FRAME must not be empty` error

Comment: I can't replicate this error. If I call an example `scatterm` and then do either `frame = getframe` or `frame = getframe(gca)`, or using `h` as the handle to the `scatterm`, `frame = getframe(get(h,'Parent'))`, these all return an appropriate `frame.cdata`.    It could be something you're doing in setting the colorbar/title info?